# Como limitar as extensões que podem ser salvas? (PHP)

Tags: php

Oi, consegui fazer rodar o código e salvar o arquivo, porém quero que salve apenas imagens. Sem o filtro ele salva qualquer tipo de arquivo. Como poderia fazer com que apenas as extensões jpg, jpeg e png possam ser salvas? Abaixo o cod.

```
<form action="proc_artigos.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <label for="">Título</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="titulo" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Imagem</label>
            <input type="file" name="imgUpload">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">      
            <label for="">Conteúdo</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="texto" rows="30" required ></textarea>
            </div>
                <input name="send" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Salvar">                      
       </form>
```

Arquivo php:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {

$file = $_FILES["imgUpload"];

if ($file["error"]) {
    throw new Exception("Error: " . $file["error"]);
}

$dirUploads = "uploads";

if (!is_dir($dirUploads)) {
    mkdir($dirUploads);
}

if (move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $dirUploads . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file["name"])) {

} else {
    throw new Exception("Não foi possível salvar o arquivo.");

  }
}
```

Obrigado!
 Obs: O restante está funcionando, quero apenas limitar as extensões dos arquivos que podem ser salvos.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo Front-end vc pode usar:

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

ou

```
 <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
```

e Pelo Back-end:

```
<?php
$arquivo = "imagem.exe";
$imagem = ".jpg";
$video = ".mp4";
$virus = ".exe";

if (substr($arquivo, -4) === $imagem) {
    echo "É imagem";
}elseif (substr($arquivo, -4) == $video) {
    echo "É vídeo";
}elseif (substr($arquivo, -4) == $virus) {
    echo "É virus";
}else{
    echo "Não sei! :-/";
}

?>
```

Comment: Até já usei, mas esqueci.

Comment: Eu estava errado. Não adianta...

Comment: Tem como alterar o MIME type também! Ou seja, não muda nada. =/

Answer (score 0):

você faz da seguinte forma no início da pagina adiciona:

```
ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);
```

isso faz não exibir um warning quando a imagem for corrompida ou o tipo de arquivo não identificado.

Dai valide assim:

```
if ((exif_imagetype($ImagePathAndName) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) && (imagecreatefromjpeg( $ImagePathAndName ) !== false ))
{
echo 'è um jpg<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu percebi você quer analisar uma IMAGEM. Logo, você pode usar o [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getimagesize.php) para saber se é realmente uma imagem. Pois ele retornará `false` se for qualquer outro arquivo. Depois você pode implementar as extensões que podem ser usadas:

```
if(($testeImage = getimagesize($file["tmp_name"])) != false){

    $exts = ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/bmp"];

    if(in_array($testeImage['mime'], $exts)){
        echo "imagem válida";
    }
}
```

Na minha opinião esta é uma solução mais segura.